# How to set a bottom margin in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, margin, fpdf

I've taken a dive into FPDF lately and something that i don't seem to understand is - why is there no way to set a bottom margin? There are functions for setting margins from the top, left and right, but not from the bottom.

I assume now that i misunderstand something basic and conceptual about how FPDF works yet i got no clue on what that could possibly be.

So to cut it down:

Is it possible to define a fixed bottom margin in FPDF?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I just found the solution - the bottom margin is simply left out of predefinition because it is part of the page break calculation process. Therefore, setting a bottom margin in itself is not possible, but it can be done using

```
SetAutoPageBreak(boolean auto, [float margin])
```

Answer (score 23):

+1 to SquareCat's answer. To expand on this a little more, if you're having trouble with text going a little bit over the auto page break, just setting SetAutoPageBreak(false) will probably be sufficient to solve the problem. For me personally this was causing trouble when creating mailing labels.

```
$fpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
```

Just make sure that you're manually breaking pages where appropriate for your PDF.

```
$fpdf->AddPage();
```

Comment: we can also use some $counter to detect the content area like > if($counter + $nextLineHeight > $contentAreaHeight) { $fpdf->AddPage(); }

Comment: +1 To this post. I was using `$fpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true)` along with manually breaking pages `$fpdf->AddPage();`, which was causing page-break issues for me. Setting `$fpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false)` fixed my issue. Thank you @LAROmega